# Python Requests Login not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to login to this website:
https://www.fotocommunity.de/login

My Python script looks like this:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'login[login]': 'myUser',
    'login[pass]': 'myPassword',
    'login[vorname]':''
}

with requests.Session() as c:

    c.post('https://www.fotocommunity.de/login', data=payload)
    r=c.get('http://www.fotocommunity.de/pc/pc/channel/8/extra/new/display/32815218')

print(r.content)
```

It is somehow not working. I dont know what I m doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you send it `'login[login]'` or `'login[pass]'`? are you sure it supposed to be that way? if it's a `dict` you want then it should be `login['login']`...

Comment: Because the form in the html sourcecode says: name="login[login]" type="text"

Comment: have you tried the `data-name` instead of the `value name`?

Comment: Yes. I tried data-name aswell. No success either.

Comment: `'myUser'` & `'myPassword'` are those valid user and password ???? it should be `myUser` & `myPassword`  as parameters of the password and user without the ' note.

Comment: When I remove the ', I get an error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. My username contains an @ sign.

Comment: You need to write between the ' ' your real password and user name....

Comment: Yes, of course I entered my real password and user name.

Comment: This is the whole line: payload = {"login": "manfred@mustermann.de", "pass": "kdjgdklfg12", "vorname":""}

Comment: Are you sure that the site isn't using JavaScript to modify the behavior of the form after the page loads?  Have you checked the request headers sent by a browser on submission and duplicated those headers in Python?  Questions like this are inevitably a poor fit for SO because they end up being about the behavior of a single website rather than programming, and are of interest to essentially one person.

Comment: I m not sure, but I guess its protected. And you are right regarding SO. Thanks!